# MySQL view with 5 table join is not returning any rows

Tags: mysql, view

Here is my view creation.. Which is not returning any rows..

```
CREATE VIEW TOP AS
(
SELECT 
a.USER_ID, a.USER_NAME, a.PASSWORD, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME, a.CONTACT_NUMBER, a.EMERGENCY_NUMBER, a.CITIZEN_SHIP, a.VISA_TYPE, 
b.PLACE_CODE, b.PLACE_NAME, b.AIR_AVAILIBILITY, b.TRAIN_AVAILIBILITY, b.ROAD_AVAILIBILITY, 
c.CLIENT_ID, c.CLIENT_NAME, c.CLIENT_ADDRESS, c.CLIENT_LOCATION,
d.PROJECT_CODE, d.PROJECT_NAME,
e.REQUEST_ID, e.REQUEST_STATUS, e.REQUEST_FOR, e.REQUEST_MODE, e.REQUEST_TYPE, e.TRAVEL_FROM, e.TRAVEL_TO, e.TRAVEL_DATE, e.TRAVEL_TICKET_BY, e.ASSIGNMENT_PLACE, 
e.ASSIGNMENT_COUNTRY, e.TRAVEL_PURPOSE, e.ASSIGNMENT_DURATION, e.ASSIGNMENT_START_DATE, e.ASSIGNMENT_ACCOMODATION_BY, e.ACCOMODATION_BILLABLE, e.TRAVEL_BILLABLE, e.ASSIGNMENT_BILLABLE, e.NSHORE_PROJECT_BILLABLE
FROM USERS a, PLACES b, CLIENTS c, PROJECTS d, REQUESTS e
WHERE 
a.USER_ID = e.USER_ID
AND b.PLACE_CODE = e.TRAVEL_FROM
AND b.PLACE_CODE = e.TRAVEL_TO
AND c.CLIENT_ID = d.CLIENT_ID
AND d.PROJECT_CODE = e.PROJECT_CODE
);
```

I think the problem is in these two lines..

```
AND b.PLACE_CODE = e.TRAVEL_FROM
AND b.PLACE_CODE = e.TRAVEL_TO
```

where I'm trying to reference to the same table more than once. Sorry if I'm asking really a very basic question. Im completely new to databases.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get separate details for the place `TRAVEL_FROM` and the place `TRAVEL_TO`.  To do that, you need to join twice against the same table with different aliases. I'm going to replace your implicit (comma-separated `FROM`) joins with explicit `INNER JOIN`s which are preferred:

```
CREATE VIEW TOP AS
(
SELECT 
  a.USER_ID, a.USER_NAME, a.PASSWORD, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME, a.CONTACT_NUMBER, a.EMERGENCY_NUMBER, a.CITIZEN_SHIP, a.VISA_TYPE, 
  /* one set of columns for TRAVEL_FROM, each with its own alias */
  b_from.PLACE_CODE AS PLACE_CODE_from, b_from.PLACE_NAME AS PLACE_NAME_from, b_from.AIR_AVAILIBILITY AS AIR_AVAILABILITY_from, b_from.TRAIN_AVAILIBILITY AS TRAIN_AVAILABILITY_from, b_from.ROAD_AVAILIBILITY AS ROAD_AVAILABILITY_from, 
  /* and one set for TRAVEL_TO, each with its own alias*/
  b_to.PLACE_CODE AS PLACE_CODE_to, b_to.PLACE_NAME AS PLACE_NAME_to, b_to.AIR_AVAILIBILITY AS AIR_AVAILABILITY_to, b_to.TRAIN_AVAILIBILITY AS TRAIN_AVAILABILITY_to, b_to.ROAD_AVAILIBILITY AS ROAD_AVAILABILITY_to, 
  c.CLIENT_ID, c.CLIENT_NAME, c.CLIENT_ADDRESS, c.CLIENT_LOCATION,
  d.PROJECT_CODE, d.PROJECT_NAME,
  e.REQUEST_ID, e.REQUEST_STATUS, e.REQUEST_FOR, e.REQUEST_MODE, e.REQUEST_TYPE, e.TRAVEL_FROM, e.TRAVEL_TO, e.TRAVEL_DATE, e.TRAVEL_TICKET_BY, e.ASSIGNMENT_PLACE, 
  e.ASSIGNMENT_COUNTRY, e.TRAVEL_PURPOSE, e.ASSIGNMENT_DURATION, e.ASSIGNMENT_START_DATE, e.ASSIGNMENT_ACCOMODATION_BY, e.ACCOMODATION_BILLABLE, e.TRAVEL_BILLABLE, e.ASSIGNMENT_BILLABLE, e.NSHORE_PROJECT_BILLABLE
FROM 
  /* implicit joins replaced with preferred explicit joins */
  USERS a
  INNER JOIN  REQUESTS e ON a.USER_ID = e.USER_ID
  /* Join frist against PLACES for TRAVEL_FROM */
  INNER JOIN PLACES b_from ON b_from.PLACE_CODE = e.TRAVEL_FROM  
  /* And again against PLACES for TRAVEL_TO */
  INNER JOIN PLACES b_to ON b_to.PLACE_CODE = e.TRAVEL_TO
  INNER JOIN PROJECTS d ON d.PROJECT_CODE = e.PROJECT_CODE
  INNER JOIN CLIENTS c ON c.CLIENT_ID = d.CLIENT_ID
);
```